# Javascript <HTML> tag onclick event.pageX comparison change

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, mouseevent

The BODY width of my `mobile sites + radio jukebox website` is 600 pixels or less (used for PCs, tablets, and smartphones).

As an experiment, I want to click any blank space to the `right of the BODY` (typically on a PC) to do something. The first test is to just jump back to the main menu. A later test is to scroll back to the top of iframe content. Since this occurs outside of the `<body>` declaration, I put an **onClick** statement in the `<html>` tag.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      onclick="var iframeX=600, evX=event.pageX; if(evX>iframeX)d123(1);">
```

Example test page: <strike>http://m.gooplusplus.com/i8-test.php</strike> (Sorry, deleted during cleanup.)

This works as long as I click to the right of the initial 600 pixels. However, when I reassign variable iframeX to a smaller value of 356, there is no action when I click in the 356-600 pixel range.

To test, go to the test page, click on the meter or info icon or any content link.

> (1) Cursor near right edge of the screen and click. You get the main menu again.
>
> (2) Click meter again and cursor just right of menu and click. Now nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some testing, I think that I figured it out.

I should `not` have set global variable iframeX in the `<html> onclick` statement. I should have deferred creating iframeX until later in one of my `<head> <script>` sections.

I don't know if this is cross-browser compatible but it works in current Windows versions of Google Chrome, Firefox, and IE 11.

The new `<html>` statements is almost the same:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      onclick="var evX=event.pageX; if(evX>iframeX)d123(1);">
```

<strike>http://m.gooplusplus.com/i8-test-solved.php</strike>

Sorry, test file was deleted during directory cleanup.  Working solution is in source code:

http://m.gooplusplus.com